# Ruby map method in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, dictionary

Can somebody help me understand which job the map functions has in this code?

```
counts = @a.group_by{|i| i}.map{|k,v| [k[0], k[1], v.count]}
```

Answer (score 4):

`@a.group_by{|i| i}` is producing an hash, where **key/value** pairs are `Array`.

Now `#map` method takes each pair. `k` is a `key`, and `v` is a value, inside `map` creating an array `[first_entry_of_array,second_entry_of_array,value_array_size]`( when key/value both are array). I said `key` can be an array, as you used `k[0]`, `k[1]`, and [`Array#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) is the method it is actually.

Example :

```
a = [ %w(foo bar) ,%W(baz bar), %w(foo bar) ]
a.group_by { |e| e } 
# => {["foo", "bar"]=>[["foo", "bar"], ["foo", "bar"]],
#     ["baz", "bar"]=>[["baz", "bar"]]}
a.group_by { |e| e }.map{|k,v| [k[0], k[1], v.count]}
# => [["foo", "bar", 2], ["baz", "bar", 1]]
```

`key` can be a **string** also. Then it is inside of `#map` will be `[first_character_of_string,second_character_of_string,value_array_size]`. The same reason as with, I doubt `key` can be a string, as those call are [`String#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method call.

Example :

```
a = %w(foo bar foo baz bar)
a.group_by { |e| e }
# => {"foo"=>["foo", "foo"], "bar"=>["bar", "bar"], "baz"=>["baz"]}
#        ^         ^
#       key      value  
a.group_by { |e| e }.map{|k,v| [k[0], k[1], v.count]}
# => [["f", "o", 2], ["b", "a", 2], ["b", "a", 1]]
```

Basically `#map` will produce here an *array of array*.

Straight from the documentation of [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) :

> Returns a new array *with the results of running block* once for every element in enum.

Here in your example, *with the results of running block*, means results are being genrated after each iteration, from the block with `#map`, is `[k[0], k[1], v.count]`.

Straight from the documentation of [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) :

> *Groups the collection* by result of the block. *Returns a hash* where the *keys are the evaluated result* from the block and the *values are arrays of elements* in the collection that correspond to the key.

Hope that helps!